# Debug query while executing in Preview Mode SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My goal is to view the query that gets executed against the server while in Preview Mode of reporting services.

Is there anyway to do this? Or another approach that I can take to debug the actual query that is being executed by my SSRS report?

I can attach the query text, however I'm more concerned that the parameters are being passed correctly to the query.

Comment: You could try to use `SQL Profiler`...

Comment: Ah, good thought. I will give that a shot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest to install
[**ExpressProfiler**](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=expressprofiler)

This is what I used to check that parameters are being passed correctly or not. Try this!